# Using let in phpspec

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, phpspec

I am trying to test a class in phpspec. The class is a regular Service class to be used in ZF2.

```
class GuestService implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{
    public static function createWithServiceManager(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $guestService = new GuestService();
        $guestService->setServiceLocator($serviceLocator);
        return $guestService;
    }

    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface  $serviceLocator)
    {
        $this->services = $serviceLocator;
    } 
}
```

My Spec is:

```
class GuestServiceSpec extends ObjectBehavior
{
    function let(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceManager)
    {
        $this->beConstructedThrough('createWithServiceManager' , [$serviceManager]);
    }
}
```

I'm having troubles understanding how phpspec will create the serviceManager object in the first place to call the constructed through function. In Zend I have a factory closure that allows that construction which is very similar to the static method given above.

I have seen an example of an object construction on [phpspec manual](http://www.phpspec.net/en/latest/cookbook/construction.html) which uses a Writer object to pass to the constructor. It however does not explain how this Writer object is created.

I can see similar examples on that page that have objects passed to phpspec functions.

```
function it_does_something_if_argument_is_false(Writer $writer)
{
    $this->beConstructedWith($writer, false);
    // constructed with second argument set to false
    // ...
}
```

But it does not explain how the Writer object is itself constructed. How will the serviceManager be constructed?

Answer (score 0):

In your case `$writer` and `$serviceManager` are **stubs**. PHPSpec parses type hints in your methods (`Writer` and `ServiceLocatorInterface`) and creates stubs using reflection. There are just copies of original classes with copied methods, but without implementation.

You can read more [here](http://www.phpspec.net/en/latest/manual/prophet-objects.html#stubs)

Answer (score 0):

To be more precise, `$writer` and `$serviceManager` are **tests doubles**.

If You test do not depends on any method from `$serviceManager` what PHPSpec will create is a **dummy** - an empty object that do not have any behavior.

You can learn more about test doubles from **Konstantin (@everzet)** presentations:
https://youtu.be/X6y-OyMPqfw?t=12m0s